# What should format use to export .key and .req file?

Tags: java, certificate, writer

I exported .key and .req file by my java application.

**Code:**

```
BufferedOutputStream bos1 = new BufferedOutputStream(                           new FileOutputStream(txtRequest.getText()));
bos1.write(certificate.getBytes());

bos1.close();

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(txtPrivateKey.getText()));
PEMWriter writer = new PEMWriter(bw);
writer.writeObject(getPrivateKey());

writer.close();
bw.close();
```

I have a problem that when I export .pfx file by using these .req and .key files. It's only get to install window XP and not get to install window server 2008 and window 7.
How should I do? Please show the way.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS12 - can be read by openssl tool and can be exported too.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS12